# Creating nested python dictionary for Dynatree

Tags: python, data-structures, dynatree

The dynatree jquery tree element can read from the following format:

```
{'title':'a','children':[{'title':'b','children':[{'title':'c','children':[]}]}]}
```

I have a path a:b:c.

How to generate nested python dictionary, given above, that will use the given path?

I have a lot of different paths some of them repeat 'a:b:c:d', adding new element, some of

them completely different?

Comment: That already is a valid Python dictionary? I’m not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the path by `:` and start from the last element, encapsulating each one into its container:

```
def path_to_tree(p):
    elems = p.split(':')
    head = None
    for elem in reversed(elems):
        head = {'title': elem, 'children': [] if head is None else [head]}
    return head
```

Comment: thank you for quick response, it is great, what if I have multiple paths like this: 'a:b:c:d' and 'a:b:e:f' how to incorporate those? thank you

Comment: @user1810100 It would be straightforward to write a recursive function that merges the dictionaries. It's not obvious how the function should behave when given paths `a:b:c` and `x:y:z`; should the resulting dict's title be `a` or `x`?

Comment: in this case -> given paths a:b:c and x:y:z - we will have two branches. I appreciate your help showing  how dictionary notation works. Fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

```
tree = {'title':'a','children':[{'title':'b','children':[{'title':'c','children':[]}]}]}
print tree['a']['b']['c']
```